# Bug in php function to replace line breaks with paragraph tags

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a php function for converting line breaks to paragraphs but ignoring any lines which are already wrapped in h, ul, ol or li tags. This works fine except if the string is as follows:

```
<h1>lkjhlkjkl</h1>
hgjk
<ul>
<li>hjgkghjk</li></ul>
ghjkghj
```

rendering as follows:

`<h1>lkjhlkjkl</h1><p>hgjk</p><ul><li>hjgkghjk</li></ul><p>ghjkghj</p>`

But if the closing ul tag is on a separate line it renders the following results:

`<h1>lkjhlkjkl</h1><p>hgjk</p><ul><li>hjgkghjk</li><p></ul><p>ghjkghj</p>`

placing a p tag before the closing ul

Here's the php:

```
<?php
function format_html($content)
 {
  $content = preg_replace("/<(h[1-6]|ul|ol|li)>\n/", "<$1>", $content);
  $content = preg_replace("/<\/(h[1-6]|ul|ol|li)>\n/", "</$1><p>", $content);
  $content = "<p>" . str_replace("\n", "</p><p>", $content);
  $content = preg_replace("/<p><(h[1-6]|ul|ol|li)>/", "<$1>", $content);
  return $content;
 }

function format_html_end($content)
 {
  $content = preg_replace("/<\/(h[1-6]|ul|ol|li)><\/p>/", "</$1>", $content);
  return $content;
 }

 echo format_html_end(format_html("$content</p>"));

?>
```

Any ideas how to prevent this small bug?

Answer (score 2):

This should work on the code example you posted. However, it matches all tags and not just the h, ul, ol and li you requested.

```
$content = preg_replace("/\n([^<>]+)/", "<p>$1</p>", $content);
$content = str_replace("\n", "", $str);
echo $content;
```

Comment: What if the line starts with a strong tag? That's why I specified what tags to apply it to.